# How to replicate conda environment from windows desktop linux server not connected to internet?

Tags: python, linux, yaml, conda, anaconda3

I have created a conda environment on my windows desktop. I am trying to move it to windows server and Linux server.
I created specification file like below which has all internal URL
[image: Spec file]

Using this spec file I could create environment on windows server not connected to internet.
For Linux server I created .yml file like below.

[image: YML File]

When I try to create environment using this .yml file on Linux server (not connected to internet) I get error like below.

Fetching package metadata ...Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/ Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/

My understanding is conda is trying to install python and other packages as .yml file is not telling it internal path. Not certain what different to do with .yml file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems pretty simple: the `.yml` file is just a *list* of the packages that are contained in the conda environment. When you try to create an environment based on the `.yml` file, conda reads all the names and versions of the packages listed, and then fetches, downloads and installs them.

Since your Linux server is **not connected to the Internet** it fails when it's trying to fetch them, since it isn't able to reach the repo in which those packages are contained. So it's not able to download and add them to the virtual environment.

Comment: So how .yml can provide internal artifactory/repo location? Specification file has that but it was windows specific

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but i think the construction of the environment starting from a .yml works something like this:
1 - Create the conda env with the name in the file
2 - Inside the created env, do: pip install x for x in list_of_dependecies, where list_of_dependencies are the elements in the .yml file.

When it tries to run pip install x, it fails due to the lack of connection.